# System.Timers.Timer Elapsed event executing after timer.Stop() is called

Tags: c#, .net, timer

**Background:** I have a timer that I am using to keep track of how long it has been since the serialPort DataReceived event has been fired. I am creating my own solution to this instead of using the built in timeout event because I am getting a continuous stream of data, instead of sending a query and getting one response.

**The Problem:**
In the DataReceived handler I have a statement to stop the timer so that is doesn't elapse. the problem is that a lot of the time it still executes the Elapsed handler afterword.

I have read that is is possible to use SynchronizingObject to solve this problem but I am not sure how to accomplish that.

**Here is my code:** I tried to cut out everything that I didn't think was relevant.

```
    private System.Timers.Timer timeOut;
    private System.Timers.Timer updateTimer;

    public void start()
    {
        thread1 = new Thread(() => record());

        thread1.Start();
    }

    public void requestStop()
    {
        this.stop = true;
        this.WaitEventTest.Set();

    }

    private void record()
    {
        timeOut = new System.Timers.Timer(500); //** .5 Sec
        updateTimer = new System.Timers.Timer(500); //** .5 Sec

        timeOut.Elapsed += TimeOut_Elapsed;
        updateTimer.Elapsed += updateTimer_Elapsed;
        updateTimer.AutoReset = true;


        comport.Open();
        comport.DiscardInBuffer();


        comport.Write(COMMAND_CONTINUOUSMODE + "\r");

        stopwatch.Reset();
        stopwatch.Start();

        recordingStartTrigger(); //** Fire Recording Started Event

        timeOut.Start();
        updateTimer.Start();

        this.waitHandleTest.WaitOne(); //** wait for test to end

        timeOut.Stop();
        updateTimer.Stop();

        comport.Write(COMMAND_COMMANDMODE + Environment.NewLine);
        comport.DiscardInBuffer();
        comport.Close();
        recordingStopTrigger(status); //** Fire Recording Stopped Event

        stopwatch.Stop();
    }


    //***********************************************************************************
    //** Events Handlers


    private void comDataReceived_Handler(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {

        double force = -100000;
        string temp = "-100000";

        //timeOut.SynchronizingObject.Invoke(new Action(()=> {timeOut.Stop();}), new object[] {sender, e});

        timeOut.Stop();

        //** I removed my action code here, keep things simple.


        timeOut.Start();
    }

    private void TimeOut_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        timeOut.Stop();
        updateTimer.Stop();


        //** fire delegate that GUI will be listening to, to update graph.
        if (eventComTimeOut != null && this.stop == false)
        {
            if (eventComTimeOut(this, new eventArgsComTimeOut(comport.PortName, "READ")))
            {
                //retry = true;
                comport.Write(COMMAND_CONTINUOUSMODE + "\r");
                updateTimer.Start();
                timeOut.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                this.stop = true;
                //retry = false;
                this.WaitEventTest.Set();
                status = eventArgsStopped.Status.failed;                     
            }
        }
    }

    void updateTimer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {

        //** fire delegate that GUI will be listening to, to update graph.
        List<Reading> temp = new List<Reading>(report.Readings_Force);
        eventNewData(this, new eventArgsNewData(temp));

    }
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This is well known behavior. `System.Timers.Timer` internally uses `ThreadPool` for execution. Runtime will queue the `Timer` in threadpool. It would have already queued before you have called `Stop` method. It will fire at the elapsed time.

To avoid this happening set `Timer.AutoReset` to false and start the timer back in the elapsed handler if you need one. Setting `AutoReset` false makes timer to fire only once, so in order to get timer fired on interval manually start timer again.

```
yourTimer.AutoReset = false;

private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
     try
     {
         // add your logic here
     }
     finally
     {
         yourTimer.Enabled = true;// or yourTimer.Start();
     }
}
```

Comment: What is the reason for adding the try finally?

Comment: @mikejames In `try` block you'll add your logic, even in case of exceptions `finally` block will ensure that yourTimer will start again.

Comment: I see that makes sense, in my case I only ever want the timer to run once. I have decided to change to System.Threading.Timer

Comment: AutoReset is not a valid timer method. It comes will red line below it!

Comment: @HilalAl-Rajhi `System.Timers.Timer` have a property named `AutoReset`

Comment: this is not answering the question. the problem is how to stop the timer correctly, not to prevent AutoReset.

Answer (score 2):

I did a pause in timer with this code. for me that works.

```
Private cTimer As New System.Timers.Timer
Private Sub inittimer()
    cTimer.AutoReset = True
    cTimer.Interval = 1000
    AddHandler cTimer.Elapsed, AddressOf cTimerTick
    cTimer.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub cTimerTick()
    If cTimer.AutoReset = True Then
       'do your code if not paused by autoreset false
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and after some trying ended up with timer object to null and replace the timer variable it with a new timer object fixed the issue. I know its heavy of resources. But it solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I added a check in the Elapsed event

```
if(_timer.Enabled)
{
   //Do something
}
```