# Only raise an event if the previous one was completed

Tags: c#, timer

I'm using a `System.Timers.Timer` in my application. Every second I run a function which does some job. The thing is, this function can block for some little time (it reads then processes a large file from disk). I want to start that function only if its previous "execution instance" has completed. I thought I could achieve this with a `Mutex`:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Timers;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static Mutex TimerMut = new Mutex(false);
        public static void Main()
        {

            Thread TT = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                System.Timers.Timer oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                oTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Handler);

                oTimer.Interval = 1000;
                oTimer.Enabled = true;
            }));

            TT.Start();

            Console.Read();
        }

        private static void Handler(object oSource,
            ElapsedEventArgs oElapsedEventArgs)
        {
            TimerMut.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("foo");
            Thread.Sleep(500);         //simulate some work
            Console.WriteLine("bar");
            TimerMut.ReleaseMutex();
        }
    }
}
```

That doesn't work, "foos" still appear every second. How can I achieve this?

EDIT: You're right, it makes no sense to start a new thread to handle this. I thought only `System.Threading.Timer` is launched in a separate thread.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Perhaps foo appears every second because your simulated work only lasts for half a second.  The problem with this approach, though, is that the Handler needs to exit without doing anything if a previous instance is running.  Your code is waiting for the previous one to finish and then continuing.  If your work takes 20 seconds, then there will be 20 calls to Handler waiting for the mutex and proceeding to do the work when the previous one exits.

Comment: [Does this helps ?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18280560/2530848)

Comment: Your code shouldn't even compile. You've declared a static variable within a method... that means the code you're running *isn't* the code you've shown us. Please produce a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: And also you have created thread for no reason.

Comment: @AlexFarber The code *doesn't* meet his requirements.  The requirements are just to skip the handler if the previous was still running, not wait for it to finish.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, my mistake, I've forgotten to paste the variable declaration (which is of course declared above main) at first, then noticed and put it in the wrong place. Corrected now.

Comment: @szczurcio: Okay, so now can you turn it into a *complete* example? We should be able to copy, paste, compile, run, observe the problem.

Comment: On a site note, you shouldn't be starting a new thread just to create a timer.  Create a timer right in the current thread.

Comment: @JonSkeet This code compiles & runs fine for me. Of course some using statements are needed.

Comment: @szczurcio: And a class declaration. So no, it doesn't satisfy my "copy, paste, compile, run" requirement. Your goal should be to make it as easy as possible for other people to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet OK, pasted complete code. The problem has been solved (thanks KeithS), but I'll keep your remarks in mind in the future :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way I know of to do this kind of thing:

```
internal static volatile bool isRunning;

public static void Main()
    {
        Thread TT = new Thread(new ThreadStart(delegate()
            {
                System.Timers.Timer oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
                oTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Handler);

                oTimer.Interval = 1000;
                oTimer.Enabled = true;                 
            }));

        TT.Start();
    }

    private void Handler(object oSource,
        ElapsedEventArgs oElapsedEventArgs)
    {
        if(isRunning) return;

        isRunning = true;

        try
        {
           Console.WriteLine("foo");
           Thread.Sleep(500);         //simulate some work
           Console.WriteLine("bar");
        }
        finally { isRunning = false; }            
    }
```

The handler still runs, but the very first thing it does is make sure that another handler isn't running, and if one is, it stops immediately.

For timers executing handlers more quickly (like 3-4 times a second), this has the possibility to race; two threads could proceed past the guard clause before one of them sets the bit. You can avoid this with a couple of `lock` statements, similar to a Mutex or Monitor:

```
    static object syncObj = new object();

    private void Handler(object oSource,
        ElapsedEventArgs oElapsedEventArgs)
    {
        lock(syncObj)
        {
           if(isRunning) return;            
           isRunning = true;
        }

        try
        {
           Console.WriteLine("foo");
           Thread.Sleep(500);         //simulate some work
           Console.WriteLine("bar");
        }
        finally { lock(syncObj) { isRunning = false; } }            
    }
```

This will ensure that only one thread can ever be examining or modifying isRunning, and as isRunning is marked volatile, the CLR won't cache its value as part of each thread's state for performance; each thread has to look at exactly the same memory location to examine or change the value.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are using a new thread to start the timer, since timers run on their own thread, but here's a method that works.  Simply turn the timer off until you are done with the current interval.

```
static System.Timers.Timer oTimer

public static void Main()
{
    oTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    oTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(Handler);

    oTimer.Interval = 1000;
    oTimer.Enabled = true;                 
}

private void Handler(object oSource, ElapsedEventArgs oElapsedEventArgs)
{
    oTimer.Enabled = false;

    Console.WriteLine("foo");
    Thread.Sleep(5000);         //simulate some work
    Console.WriteLine("bar");

    oTimer.Enabled = true;
}
```

Comment: This is actually different.  The next tick will be 1 second after the previous tick finishes.  If it takes 1.5 seconds that means the second tick is 2.5 seconds after the very start, not 2 seconds after the very start.

Comment: @Servy Sometimes this is the desired behavior. If I would be the OP reading a large file, I would choose this.

Comment: @Alb Sure, there are all sorts of behaviors that aren't what the question was asking for that are desirable in other situations.  But the point is that this doesn't address the problem being asked about.  I never said this is never suitable, just that it doesn't solve the problem at hand.

Comment: @Servy Well, if we take the question character by character, your solution answers very precisely with a smart (I even risk that: with the best) idea. And if we take reality: working with big files is not something you want to do frequently. Apart from that, the above solution is the most readable and the most simple out of all. As a good teacher said once: "*if you can solve it simply, why do it complex*", I would spare your good solution to a case where there is a strict specification to that 1 sec. I even would mention it in your answer, but that's only how I think. :)

Comment: @Alb How readable or simple a solution is *when it behaves incorrectly* is irrelevant.  Simple solutions are certainly preferable to complex solutions *when they behave identically*.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to skip the tick if another is already working you can do this.

```
private readonly object padlock = new object();

private void SomeMethod()
{
    if(!Monitor.TryEnter(padlock))
        return;

    try
    {
        //Do heavy work
    }
    finally
    {
        Monitor.Exit(padlock);
    }
}
```

Comment: Locking is a bit of overreaction for these kinds of jobs. Also, locking syntax has changed over time: you should update. :)

Comment: @Alb Locking is an entirely reasonable consideration, given that the problem requires synchronization across threads.  While it's *possible* to avoid it, as seen in my answer, prefering locks is not unreasonable .  Also if you *did* want to use a monitor, this is the appropriate way to do it, there's not really a different syntax that's any better.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the following pattern to skip doing the indicated work if another invocation of this method is still running:

```
private int isWorking = 0;
public void Foo()
{
    if (Interlocked.Exchange(ref isWorking, 1) == 0)
    {
        try
        {
            //Do work
        }
        finally
        {
            Interlocked.Exchange(ref isWorking, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

The approach that you were using with a `Mutex` will result in addition ticks *waiting for earlier ticks to finish*, not *skipping invocations when another is still running*, which is what you said you wanted.  (When dealing with timers like this its common to want to skip such ticks, not wait.  If your tick handlers regularly take too long you end up with a giant queue of waiting handlers.)

Comment: This looks complicated. Does it does the same as `if(mutex.WaitOne(0)) { /* do work */; mutes.ReleaseMutex(); }` but *more efficient* or what?

Comment: @Sinatr It has *radically* different semantics.  This skips executing the code if it is currently working.  You are describing code that would wait until another invocation finished and then start doing the work.  I even explain the difference between these options in my answer.

Comment: Nope, `mutex.WaitOne(0)` will check, but won't block anything. If you get `true` (and only one thread will get it) - mutex is owned and you can do work. I haven't seen your pattern before, so was curious if it's better than using `Mutex`.