# ObjectDisposedException after closing application on Timer

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, timer, task

Im working on a Network application. First I wanted to make DataGridView to refresh its data on every second. My implementation:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    BindingList<Wifi> Networks = new BindingList<Wifi>();
    System.Timers.Timer NetworksRefreshThread;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NetshScanner netshScanner = new NetshScanner();
        NetworksRefreshThread = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        dataGridView1.DataSource = Networks;
        NetworksRefreshThread.Elapsed += delegate
        {         
            BindingList<Wifi> tmp = new BindingList<Wifi>(netshScanner.StartAndParseOutput());

                this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
                {
                    Networks.Clear();
                    foreach (Wifi net in tmp)
                    {
                        Networks.Add(net);
                    }

                });

        };
    }
```

After closing the form, I get ObjectDisposedException inside the this.Invoke. Any advice?

Comment: Do you stop the timer running when closing the form?

Comment: I added the NetworksRefreshThread.Close() in the Form1_FormClosing event but still the same. I would add that this exception not always appears.

Comment: [This will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

What's probably happening is that the timer has fired and is currently busy refreshing your DataGridView. This happens on a seperate thread.
Then when you are closing the form, the GUI thread starts destroying its objects.
After that, the timer is done retrieving its new data but has no object left to put it.

To solve this. Add a boolean to your class called 'Updating' or something similar. Then set its value when you are updating to true.

```
NetworksRefreshThread.Elapsed += delegate
{    
    Updating = true;     
    BindingList<Wifi> tmp = new BindingList<Wifi>(netshScanner.StartAndParseOutput());

        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            Networks.Clear();
            foreach (Wifi net in tmp)
            {
                Networks.Add(net);
            }

        });
    Updating = false;
};
```

Now create a new method which you bind to the Form closing down event. In this method, do a Thread.Sleep() while the timer is updating:

```
while (Updating) Thread.Sleep(100);
```

Comment: But the updating stuff is done in the GUI thread, thats why I used the `this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate)`. Inside the timer I obtain the data to the `tmp` variable and give it to the GUI thread for updating.

Comment: Well, you TRY to make the GUI thread do it... but the GUI thread is no longer there after you close the form.

Comment: It seems to be the problem but when I modified the code with the `Update` boolean the application freezes when the situation appears.