# Process launched by a timer ignore WaitForExit()

Tags: c#, timer, process

Coding a service, every 3 seconds it calls ElapsedEventhandler to call external program.
It must wait to wait to process WaitForExit but it doesn't...

Something related to different threads?

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;    

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer(3000D);
    timer.AutoReset = true;
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(this.timer_Elapsed);
    timer.Start();
}

private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Process p = new Process();
    p.StartInfo.FileName = @"D:\go.bat";
    p.Start();
    p.WaitForExit();
}
```

"go.bat" it's a simple 3 seconds sleep (ping 192.0.2.2 -n 1 -w 10000 > nul) just for test.

Thanks!

Edit:

On the eventhandler, timer.Stop() and timer.Start() did the trick...
It makes sense that the timer is not blocked, so it raises the handler every 3 seconds...

Thanks!

Comment: How did you found out it doesn't wait?

Comment: I'd seriously recommend against blocking code in Timer callbacks. These run in the ThreadPool, where blocking code might cause ThreadPool starvation and mess you up. If you really need to block, do it in another (non-ThreadPool) thread.

Comment: I used a log, writing "DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy h:mm tt") + "start..."" and "stop..." I can see in the log 4/5 starts before the first stop...

Comment: Still I don't see the problem. If your observation is that you see multiple processes are started before one finishes, That is because Timers execute in threadpool and it won't wait for previous callback to complete. If you want to execute only one callback at a time ever refer my [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called/18280560#18280560)

Comment: You are right, actually i was editing the answer. Stoping and starting the timer in the handler fix it. It's a normal behaviour. Thanks!

Comment: Timer.AutoReset is a *lethal* property.  It will just keep starting threads to run your Elapsed event handler, regardless if the previous one hasn't finished yet.  Only ever set it to *true* if you are 100% sure that this kind of re-entrancy is never possible, you cannot get that from a 3 second Interval.  Using Stop/Start is *not* a fix, it just looks like one.  Using try/catch in the event handler is also *not* optional.  System.Timers.Timer is really rather a lousy class.