# C# - System.Timers.Timer will not turn off

Tags: c#, timer

I have a system that runs on two timers (Clock and IntervalCounter). Clock uses a tick event handler to update the display on every tick (every second), which is simple enough. IntervalCounter uses an 'elapsed' event handler which outputs a messageBox to tell the user that it is time to enter the next set of data (every 5 minutes).

There is a point during the program where I want the intervalCounter to turn off as the alerts are no longer required, but no matter how I try to make this happen, the alerts continue coming. I have tried to connect the two timers so that when Clock is off, IntervalCounter is also off, but this doesn't seem to be taking effect.

The code that initialises and runs the functions to the timer event handlers is shown below, as well as the button click at the point where I want IntervalCounter to turn off:

'Clock' functions:

```
    private void initialiseClock() //initialisation of Clock Timer
    {
        Clock = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
        Clock.Tick += new EventHandler(Clock_Tick); //calls Clock EventHandler
        Clock.Interval = 1000; //1 second in miliseconds
        Clock.Start();
    }

    //initialiseClock sub-functions
    private void Clock_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) //Clock EventHandler definition
    {
        updateTimeDisplay();
        checkDisplay();
    }
    //end initialiseClock sub-functions
```

'IntervalCounter' functions:

```
    private void initialiseIntervalCounter() //initialisation of IntervalCounter Timer
    {
        System.Timers.Timer intervalCounter = new System.Timers.Timer();
        intervalCounter.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(intervalAlert); //calls intervalCounter EventHandler
        intervalCounter.Interval = 300000; //5 minutes in miliseconds
        if (Clock.Enabled == true) //set intervalCounter to rely on Clock
        {
            intervalCounter.Enabled = true; //turn on when Clock is on
            intervalCounter.Start();
        }
        else if (Clock.Enabled == false)
        {
            intervalCounter.Enabled = false; //turn off when Clock is off
            Clock.Stop();
            intervalCounter.Stop();
        }
    }

    //initialiseIntervalCounter sub-functions
    private void intervalAlert(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e) //intervalCounter EventHandler definition
    {
        Clock.Enabled = false;
        string alertTitle = "Interval Alert";
        string alertMessage = "The 5 minute interval has been reached, enter the current readings";
        clearInput();
        DialogResult okRes = MessageBox.Show(alertMessage, alertTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
        if (okRes == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            Clock.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    //end initialiseIntervalCounter sub-functions
```

btnFinish process (where IntervalCounter should disable):

```
    private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clock.Enabled = false; //turn off Clock (and reliant Timers)
        string finishmsg = "Save monitoring data and end monitoring"; //message displayed to user
        string finishTitle = "End Monitoring Confirmation"; //title of the message box
        DialogResult finishRes = MessageBox.Show(finishmsg, finishTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question); //display messageBox and options
        if (finishRes == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            saveFileFooter(); //append the footer template and associated variable values to the text file
            saveBPChartImage();
            MessageBox.Show("The vitals data recorded in this program has been saved to the file: " +
                            fileName + //file name specified
                            "\nThe recovery data fields can now be filled in"); //give user file address and direct to completing recovery data
            enableRecoveryData();

            intervalCounter.Stop();
            StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
        else
        {
            Clock.Enabled = true;
            intervalCounter.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
```

Any suggestions on where to go from here would be class, thankyou!

Mark

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called

Comment: You are making multiple mistakes, you'll never get this code going.  You are not ready yet for System.Timers.Timer.  Franky, few programmers ever are, it is a very nasty class.  There's just no benefit to it at all in this code, just use a regular System.Windows.Forms.Timer().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that on the Timer.Elapsed Event [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Even if SynchronizingObject is not null, Elapsed events can occur after the Dispose or Stop method has been called or after the Enabled property has been set to false, because the signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread. One way to resolve this race condition is to set a flag that tells the event handler for the Elapsed event to ignore subsequent events.

Maybe you should try adding a flag to your "intervalAlert" Event handler. Something like this :

```
    bool alertIsOFF = false; // Global variable

    private void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clock.Enabled = false; //turn off Clock (and reliant Timers)
        string finishmsg = "Save monitoring data and end monitoring"; //message displayed to user
        string finishTitle = "End Monitoring Confirmation"; //title of the message box
        DialogResult finishRes = MessageBox.Show(finishmsg, finishTitle, MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question); //display messageBox and options
        if (finishRes == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            saveFileFooter(); //append the footer template and associated variable values to the text file
            saveBPChartImage();
            MessageBox.Show("The vitals data recorded in this program has been saved to the file: " +
                            fileName + //file name specified
                            "\nThe recovery data fields can now be filled in"); //give user file address and direct to completing recovery data
            enableRecoveryData();

            intervalCounter.Stop();
            alertIsOff = true;
            StopWatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        }
        else
        {
            Clock.Enabled = true;
            intervalCounter.Enabled = true;
        }
    }

    //initialiseIntervalCounter sub-functions
    private void intervalAlert(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)         //intervalCounter EventHandler definition
    {
        if (!alertIsOff)
        {
            Clock.Enabled = false;
            string alertTitle = "Interval Alert";
            string alertMessage = "The 5 minute interval has been reached, enter the current readings";
            clearInput();
            DialogResult okRes = MessageBox.Show(alertMessage, alertTitle, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
            if (okRes == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                Clock.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

    }
    //end initialiseIntervalCounter sub-functions
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you perhaps just made a trivial programming error. The code will - as shown - not compile, because your intervalConter is a local variable in initialiseIntervalCounter(). Maybe you declared it separately as a class variable, which would perfectly explain the described behaviour. Otherwise, it should work.