# How to start a second timer in c# windows forms?

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer

I have 2 timers in my form,and I can start the first timer when I click on the button but I also want the second timer to start when the first timer ends.

Comment: When your first timer ends? if you want to start second timer when first timer elapsed then use handler of first timer.

Comment: I already have.I have just started programming and I am learning as I go along.

Comment: Here is a good example for you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called)

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are making use of a countdown timer so you are tracking the timeLeft somewhere, so in the eventHandler of the timer you can do this:

```
private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(timeLeft > 0)
    {
        //Keep track of the time for timer 1, if it isn't 0 subtract it by 1.
        timeLeft = timeLeft - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Means timeLeft reached 0, so we have to stop timer1, and activate timer 2.
        timer1.Stop();
        timer2.Enabled = true;
    }
}
```