# Stopped System.Timers.Timer starts firing Elapsed event after setting AutoReset

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I have detected strange behavior of `System.Timers.Timer`:

1. Timer is created with interval of 1 second and `AutoReset` set to `false`.
2. Timer is started and `Elapsed` event is fired in 1 second. Inside event handler `timer.Enabled` is `false` which is expected because `AutoReset` was set to `false`.
3. Then no `Elapsed` events are fired which is expected since timer is stopped.
4. If now we set `timer.AutoReset` to `true`, `Elapsed` event starts firing every 1 second. `timer.Enabled` is still false.

Is it a bug in `Timer` code or may be there is a reason for such odd behavior?

In my understanding, stopped timer should not start firing events, even if we change `AutoReset` property.
I know that `Elapsed` event could be fired after timer was stopped, because execution was already queued in thread pool (problem is described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18280330/system-timers-timer-elapsed-event-executing-after-timer-stop-is-called)). However it does not explain why stopped timer starts firing events.

Here is a minimal sample that reproduces the problem:

```
class Program
{
    private static System.Timers.Timer timer;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        timer = new System.Timers.Timer
        {
            AutoReset = false,
            Interval = 1000
        };
        timer.Elapsed += TimerTick;

        LogMessage("Starting timer...");
        timer.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        LogMessage($"Timer is {(timer.Enabled ? "enabled" : "stopped")}");
        LogMessage("Setting AutoReset to true");
        timer.AutoReset = true;

        Thread.Sleep(Int32.MaxValue);
    }

    private static void TimerTick(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        LogMessage($"Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is {timer.Enabled}");
    }

    private static void LogMessage(string message)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:HH:mm:ss.fff} {message}");
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
19:46:23.043 Starting timer...
19:46:24.068 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:26.053 Timer is stopped
19:46:26.057 Setting AutoReset to true
19:46:27.100 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:28.103 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:29.117 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:30.130 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:31.144 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
19:46:32.158 Timer Tick: timer.Enabled is False
...
```

Comment: It is a deeply flawed class in many respects.  There has to be a good war story about how this class happened, I'd guess at a usability study that showed that nobody could figure out how to use System.Threading.Timer.  But yes, this is consistent with the way its code was written.  You'd normally always, always set the Enabled property back to true and flipping AutoReset to true in Elapsed never makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

**According to MS**

> The event-handling method might run on one thread at the same time that
>   another thread calls the Stop method or sets the Enabled property to
>   false. This might result in the Elapsed event being raised after the
>   timer is stopped. The example code for the Stop method shows one way
>   to avoid this race condition.
>
> Even if `SynchronizingObject` is not null, Elapsed events can occur
>   after the `Dispose` or `Stop` method has been called or after the `Enabled`
>   property has been set to `false`, because the signal to raise the
>   `Elapsed` event is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread.
>   One way to resolve this race condition is to `set a flag` that tells the
>   event handler for the `Elapsed` event to `ignore subsequent events`.

Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx
Following the trail, the recommended sample for using System.Timers.Timer and preventing unwanted `events` is the second sample at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx

It appears my previous investigation was not entirely correct. I would not say entirely wrong either. I think most of my assumptions were correct, and await feedback to improve the answer!

## My original answer

### a.k.a. descent to the darkness of System.Timers.Timer

I have not proven any of this, I have only studied the structure of the class. It's bad...

**The timer is not stopped! Enabled != Stopped**

Well, you never really called `timer.Stop()` now, did you? Like Uncle Bob says, many things in programming come in pairs, such as calls to `Start` and `Stop`. You should `Stop` the timer if you do not want it to react to your changes!

**The behaviour is correct**

I have rarely if ever used this class, but the behaviour appears to be by design. I know this sounds oxymoronic, but read below :)

Looking at the reference source, as soon as you call `myTimer.Start()`, every time you change the properties (`AutoReset`,`Interval`,`Enabled`), the timer reacts through a method called `UpdateTimer`, generating subsequent event fires as the new parameter ensemble dictates.

- Not a bug, but still a bit unsettling: A `System.Timers.Timer` with `AutoReset` set to `false`, after `Start()` and firing once, will still have a `System.Threading.Timer` roaming around. See below for explanation.

**But there is a state/display bug! At least in my opinion**

- If we changed step 4 to update `Interval` instead, which would generate a `tick`, I would expect the timer to have`Enabled==false` when the `LogMessagefunction` is called, which is already the case.
- When setting `AutoReset` to `true`, (Step 4) I would expect `Enabled` to become `true`, which as you pointed out is not the case. Let's dig deeper!

**Possible reason the state is not consistent with the behaviour**

- In the Timer.cs class, the `Enabled` setter is responsible for creating and disposing `System.Threading.Timer` instances for the backing field `timer`.

  - State change from `false` to `true` creates `timer`
  - State change from `true` to `false` disposes`timer` + some other magic.
- The only methods that use the `Enabled` property are `Start` and `Stop`
- The internal callback used to fire the events, `MyTimerCallback`, sets the `enabled` backing field to `false` when `autoreset` is `false`. In a sense it is lying, since it  circumvented the `Enabled` property on purpose to keep `timer` alive and kicking. If it were not, the behaviour of the class would not be as described above.
- My naive mind thinks that the "display bug" fix would be in `MyTimerCallback`, with a similar check to that one setting `enabled` to `false` when autoreset is `false`. Possibly even `enabled = autoreset`. I need to take a long bath after this, and go to sleep =))

Source: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs,050a7911a328d317

I think the question should be updated to better describe the behaviour, this was all news to me :)

Comment: The problem reproduces also if I stop timer explicitly. You could check it by adding `timer.Stop()` after `Thread.Sleep(3000)`.

Comment: @CodeFuller And I wanted to sleeep :((((

Comment: @CodeFuller I will go sleep now, tough day tomorrow. I don't know why this class ever saw the light of day, it seems heavily flawed. I will have to re-assess my assumptions in a better state of mind than now, but I question if the time is worth it :) I understand the curiosity, and I might dig into this from pure "why"-itis... But still, nightmares are ensured! One last interesting thing: only the first Interval change fires after the timer is stopped with .Stop().

Comment: @CodeFuller is this a dupe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/18280560/8695782 I will really go sleep now

Comment: No, it's not a duplicate. When posting the question, I have provided the same link and explained why it's not the same issue.

Comment: @CodeFuller did you read my updated answer? The explanation for the behaviour you have seems to be described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.stop(v=vs.110).aspx (check out the second code sample)

Comment: This MSDN article addresses another problem - when timer sends event already queued in thread pool. In my question I have pointed that this is not the case, since no events are sent until `AutoReset` is set to `true`.

Comment: Even if SynchronizingObject is not null, Elapsed events can occur after the Dispose or Stop method has been called or after the Enabled property has been set to false, because the signal to raise the  Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread. One way to resolve this race condition is to set a flag that tells the event handler for the Elapsed event to ignore subsequent events. Keyword "always"!

Comment: @CodeFuller forgot to tag you

Comment: Seems like the problem is not in race condition or events queued before time stop. There is a time span of 2 seconds after first timer tick and before setting `AutoReset`, and no events are fired during this interval.

Comment: I guess it is just pure curiosity to know why this happens? There are plenty of ways to work around it! I will try a debugging session this weekend